# Problem in MS Access Database During Form Value Transfer to Another Form

Tags: ms-access

I have one MS Access Database like Billing
In this Database I have two form.... 1st Form is Bill_Entry and 2nd Form is Party_Detail
I have one Textbox i.e. Party_Code in Bill_Entry Form
I have to get value in Party_Code from Party_Detail Form to Bill_Entry Form
So, how can do this

I have no idea about this

Comment: Have a combobox on Bill_Entry for selection of party. Or have a form/subform where main form is bound to Party_Detail table and subform is bound to Bill_Entry table.

Comment: Otherwise, need complicated VBA code to pass data between independently opened forms.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the afterUpdateEvent of the textbox control which is triggered by tabbing out of the textbox for instance.  you get a better user experience by using listboxes or comboboxes for Party_Code in the Bill entry form.  Whatever controls you use you have to handle updating the forms yourself.

For instance: consider two forms A & B.  Box1onFormA is unbound, Box1onFormB is bound.

```
'FormA code behind
Private Sub Box1onFormA_AfterUpdate()
Forms![FormB]![Box1onFormB] = Me.Box1onFormA
setPropertyA (Me.Box1onFormA) 'setProperty
setPropertyB (Me.Box1onFormA + 5)
Forms![FormB].Refresh 'show changes
End Sub

'FormB Code behind
Private Sub Box1onFormB_AfterUpdate()
Forms![FormA]![Box1onFormA] = Me.Box1onFormB 'set control directly
Forms![FormA].Refresh 'show changes

setPropertyA (Me.Box1onFormB)
Forms![FormB].Refresh
End Sub
```

```
'code module so properties can be accessed anywhere
Private myPropertyA As Double

Public Function getPropertyA() As Double
getPropertyA = Nz(myPropertyA, 0)
End Function

Public Function getPropertyB() As Double 'values in tables persist even when you close the database
getPropertyB = Nz(DLookup("SettingValue", "Settings", "ID = 1"), 0)
End Function

Public Function setPropertyA(value As Double)
myPropertyA = value
End Function

Public Function setPropertyB(value As Double)
'normally I would just save and load the setting on opening and closing the database for unneeded speed

Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Settings WHERE ID = 1")
rs.MoveFirst
rs.Edit
rs!SettingValue = value
rs.Update
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiaua.png)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]